# how to check current system date format?

Tags: vb.net, date-format

How can i check the system date format? Tried with the code below, but when i change my system's date format to another date format to test the code, it's still showing the date format before changed!

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern()
```

Comment: The value is cached and/or fixed when the program starts (not sure which, not going to check), since someone *changing* their regional settings whilst a program is running is not an expected use case. Did you actually restart your program after changing the settings?

Answer (score 9):

Ok. I managed to find the solution, the **'CurrentCulture'** has to be **'CurrentUICulture'**, instead of CurrentCulture. Which is as below:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern()
```